# Graph theory drawing non isomorphic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

> List all possible non-isomorphic graphs of order 6 and size 13.

So I started drawing graphs and I just think there has to be a theorem or a more efficient way of listing these graphs than by drawing them out one by one. Any help, leads, hints will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you say "order 6 and size 13" do you mean to say that there are six vertices and 13 edges?  How many edges are possible in a simple graph with six vertices?  (*does the phrase "six choose two" mean anything to you?*).  Try organizing your thoughts in terms of instead of "what edges are present" instead as "what edges are **not** present."

Comment: Yes I do mean 6 vertices and 13 edges. There are 15 edges possible in a simple 6 vertices graph, so I just delete 2 of them at a time and I could get there. How will I avoid repeats though? and could you elaborate on 6 choose 2 - can't relate that. @JMoravitz

Comment: Let's start with an easier problem. Can you list all possible non-isomorphic graphs of order $6$ and size $2$? All right, now what can you say about their complements? If a graph has order $6$ and size $2$ what order and size does the complement have? Do isomorphic graphs have isomorphic complements? Do non-isomorphic graphs have non-isomorphic complements?>

Comment: @bof THANKYOU! I see it now, just to confirm my answer though - I could come up with 3 non-isomorphic graphs with size 2. Therefore, 3 non-isomorphic graphs with size 13. Is this correct?

Comment: "*could you elaborate on 6 choose 2*"  That phrase was meant to remind you how many edges maximum are possible, $\binom{6}{2}$ (*read aloud as $6$ choose $2$*) is the binomial coefficient, the number of ways of selecting two objects from six distinct objects where order doesn't matter, i.e. in this case, the number of edges in the complete graph on six vertices.  $\binom{6}{2}=\frac{6!}{2!(6-2)!}=\frac{6\cdot 5}{2}=15$.  As far as how to continue, as bof says (and I implied in my first comment) looking at the graphs of order 6 size 2 should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: Could you describe those three graphs?  I'm afraid I would not expect an answer of three, but rather of two.  (*think of where are the two edges in relation to one another?*)

Comment: How do you get $3$? I only see two: $K_2+K_2+K_1+K_1$ and $P_3+K_1+K_1+K_1.$

Comment: I see why there should be 2 graphs.